# Eclipse - Error: Could not find or load main class seleniumpackage.Sample

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

[package path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/toh0D.png)  hi friends,

am sorry to post this question as i know this question was already answered many times but the reason i post is am new to java, selenium & eclipse.

have browsed through the answers and infact tried some of the solutions but still facing the below error message.

Error: Could not find or load main class seleniumpackage.Sample

below is my simple program in which i try to open chrome browser and access facebook home page.

```
package seleniumpackage;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Sample {

    public WebDriver good;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Users/hp/Downloads/Chrome/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver good = new ChromeDriver();
        good.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
                }
}
```

have added chrome browser, selenium client, referenced libraries jar files etc but still facing the error.

please help.

Comment: Try `Project-> Clean` or alternatively try restarting your eclipse.

Comment: First you have to leave your project error clean: The red exclamation sign that appears over your project's place means something is still wrong: Open the "problems" view and read it.